# Adobe Illustrator Does Not Allow Me to Snap to Pixel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, artboard

Illustrator CS5 on Windows 7.

I have an artboard where I keep trying to move anchors onto even-pixel points and they keep moving back to odd numbers.

E.g. I have these two anchor points on a path:

x: 999.33 px y: 0.5 px
x: 1075.25 px y: 0.5 px

I can drag the 1st anchor pretty much wherever I want. When I drag the 2nd anchor, it seems to stick, but as soon as I let go of the mouse button it snaps back, and so does the 1st anchor!

How do I fix this insane behavior? I tried aligning the artboard it's on perfectly to the overall grid, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stroke on the path take it off. Illustrator by default puts the path in the middle and half the stroke on each side of the path.  I've noticed  after aligning to a whole X/Y position, modifying the stroke size changes the path location.

It also could be View>Snap To Point or View>Snap To Grid, I forgot which was available in CS5. Im on CC.

In the past I've used JSX to script path/anchor position rounding.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into prefs to "guides and grids" and set your grid to a 1 pixel grid by setting 1px in the "gridline every 1px". In your document turn on grid by using this key command:  "command+" " If you do this you can keep snap to grid on. Also go to view/snap to grid. Like one of the posters said above, make sure fill is selected and not outline. This works very well when making say an icon.

So with that being said I was doing a test and I noticed that if I turned all of these options off place a shape randomly on the screen and then tuned the options on that the shape wouldn't snap to the grid. I had to delete the shape and make a new one and then the shape snapped so this might be a bug. Give this a try and I think you will be ok

Answer (score 0):

Creative Suite 5 did not have the Align to Pixel Grid feature. There's not a great deal you can do to align to pixels. Switching to points may help.

(Not really understanding your logic with .33 or .5 pixels.. .....no such animal exists. Pixels are whole integers.

Comment: I know real pixels are whole integers, but somehow Illustrator is snapping my anchors to fractional pixels. It is maddening. I have gone through 20 points, manually altering them all to cut off their decimals, and then discover that they've all snapped to some strange fractional pixel again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have `Snap to Grid` turned on in the View menu, and the grid doesn't correspond to pixels.

Try turning off the grid and using the Control Panel to explicitly set the location of each point, or setting the grid in `Preferences > Grids and Guides` to exact pixels.